# How to bind two values using rivets(like some or condittion)?

Tags: rivets.js

I want to bind two values to a DOM element using rivets like user.name and  user.id so that it will take user.name if it is there or user.id if user.name is empty. Can someone tell me if this is possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a oneway binder to achieve this

http://rivetsjs.com/docs/guide/#binders

An example is at http://jsfiddle.net/jWVDu/1/

```
<li rv-each-person="people" rv-data-pid="person.id">
   <span rv-nameorid="person.name"></span>
```

Basically set up a new data attribute for the id (rv-data-pid), then pass the name to the binder (rv-nameorid).  the binder then checks value (name) and if it is blank uses it, otherwise it uses the data attribute which has the id.

Comment: In one way binder i can bind only one value. But i need to pass two values. Can i pass two values?? Could u give me an example..

Comment: In chrome this is working perfectly fine.But in firefox when i run this i got the following output. Do you know why?? Example: Name = Joe Blogs Id = 100 Test = Joe Blogs Name = Fred Smith Id = Test = Fred Smith Name = Id = 50 Test = Name = Id = 99 Test =

Comment: Hi - i think that is because firefox is binding in a different order. I have updated the answer above - basically binding the placing of the person.id to the parent element so we know it is done first.

Comment: I'm not able to +1 ur comment. But the credits should go to you