# Rivets.js attribute depends on several fields

Tags: javascript, templates, ejs, rivets.js

For example I have following piece of code in EJS:

```
<img src="<%= model.image %>" title="Toggle: <%= model.brandName %> <%= model.productName %>" />
```

How can I write it in rivets.js template syntax?
rv-title may help, but I should put 'Toggle:' text to my model and create a method which will concatenate it with brandName and productName. But I don't want to do as it's not model's responsibility. Any ideas on how should it work in rivets.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a oneway binder to achieve this

http://rivetsjs.com/docs/guide/#binders

take a look at my answer at [How to bind two values using rivets(like some or condittion)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952822/how-to-bind-two-values-using-rivetslike-some-or-condittion/)   for a similar situation.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me. I thought there's more general solution like titile="Toggle: { model.brandName } { model.productName }", but seem like there isn't